# What is the difference betweeen these two pieces of codes?

Tags: c++

Can you tell me how these two are different?

```
int i = + +0;

int i = ++0; // compiler error
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first line has a space between the two pluses, the second line doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

The first one has a whitespace between the first `+` and the second `+`, the second one hasn't.

This means the first parses as two instances of the unary prefix operator `+`, while the latter parses as the unary prefix operator `++` (which of course cannot be applied to a  literal).

Comment: @KerrekSB It was meant to point out why `++` won't apply to a literal, not to imply the existence of modifiable literals. But I removed it, hoping to improve clarity.

Comment: I'm tempted to define a user-defined literal with class-type value and overload an `operator++` for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are used two different operators in these declarations.

In the first declaration there is used twice the unary plus operator. For built-in types it simply returns the value of its promoted operand. So in fact it has no any meaning that is this declaration

```
int i = + +0;
```

is equivalent to

```
int i = 0;
```

You could even write

```
int i = + + + + + +0;
```

but the result would not be changed.:)

In the second declaration there is used the unary prefix increment operator ++. It may not be applied to rvalues. So the compiler will issue an error.

The declaration would be compiled if you would add one more dclaration. For example

```
int j = 0;
int i = ++j;
```

In this case lvalue j may be incremented. The result of the initializer expression will be equal to 1 that is i will be initialized by 1 and of course j itself will be also equal to 1..

Also take into account that you may write for example any even number of pluses before j in the example above. For example

```
int j = 0;
int i = ++++++++++++j;
```

But you may use only one pair of pluses after j. For example

```
int j = 0;
int i = j++++; // compilation error.
```

But it is another question.:)

Take into account that (C++ Standard)

> 1 Expressions with unary operators group right-to-left

and prefix increment operator ++ and the unary plus operator are both unary operators.